# Is "telecommunications industry development insight" a correct/clear title?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I am translating a prensentation. And the work in progress translated title is "telecommunications industry development insight". I know instinctively that this is not quite right because one cannot stick so many nouns together like this. I want to know if this title is correct and exactly what rule or grammar of English this violates if does. Or if it is about semantic clarity, then please suggest a better version.

One little note, is the word "development" redundant? Is it already implied by "insight"? Insight is about explaining how something becomes what it is today and what to expect from it tommorow right? If so I can delete "development" and "telecommunications industry insight" is acceptable right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "telecommunications industry development insight"

It depends what the title is supposed to mean. I read it as meaning:

"An insight into the  development of the telecommunications industry"

Is that what *you* want it to mean?

Although a not very arresting or inspiring title, your version would be understood immediately in its original form in a presentation or a journal.